# What does the uppercase greek symbol pi mean for sets?

Tags: notation

What operation is denoted in e.g.:

$\Pi_{i \in I} S_i$

The document in question is:

[John C. Reynolds - Types, abstraction, and parametric polymorphism](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2010/course/DAT140_Types/Reynolds_typesabpara.pdf)

Since no index order is specified, the operation must be commutative and associative.

I am thinking that is means intersection, based on the idea that union is like addition, and intersection like multiplication. But I want to confirm it.

Thanks.

Comment: What is it's name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It usually stands for the cartesian product of the $S_i$, that is the set
\[
\prod_{i\in I} S_i = \left\{f \colon I \to \bigcup_{i\in I} S_i \biggm| f(i) \in S_i \text{ for all } i \in I\right\} 
\]